# What major Native American tribes were around Santa Fe during the late 1850s?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, native-americans, new-mexico

This question is rather basic and self-explanatory, yet I can't find answers to it when I look it up. I would appreciate if someone could give me at least 2-3 tribes which were around the Santa Fe area during 1856-1859.

Comment: Find the closest pueblos.

Comment: Welcome to HistorySE, @InventPalooza ! What has your research shown you so far?
Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find
it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help]. You may improve your
question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask].
Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are two maps at different levels of detail showing  traditional homelands in today's New Mexico:

[image: New Mexican tribes]
[image: New Mexican tribes]

Comment: Where did you find these pictures? I attempted to find something like this but was unable to! Props to you!

Comment: Thanks! I think I just looked through the image results for search terms "'new mexico' tribes".

Comment: I appreciate this greatly! I looked that term up and got plenty of information...